# Difference B/W Clock.systemUTC() And System.currentTimeMillis()

Tags: java

`Clock.systemUTC()` docs say that this method may use `System.currentTimeMillis()` or a higher resolution clock if available. What clock does `System.currentTimeMillis()` use then? Can there be a difference in the granularity of these two values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can there be a difference in the granularity of these two values?

The [`Clock`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Clock.html) class has 2 methods for retrieving the current time:

- [`millis()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Clock.html#millis())
- [`instant()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Clock.html#instant())

Since `instant()` returns an [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html), which can represent time with a precision of nano-seconds, the answer is obvious.

*Answer:* Yes.

---

> What clock does System.currentTimeMillis() use then?

If you look at the source code of `Clock.systemUTC()`, you will find that it uses an internal `SystemClock` class. In a comment in the `millis()` method, it says (quoting Java 15):

> `System.currentTimeMillis()` and `VM.getNanoTimeAdjustment(offset)`
> **use the same time source** - `System.currentTimeMillis()` simply
> limits the resolution to milliseconds.
> So we take the faster path and call `System.currentTimeMillis()`
> directly - in order to avoid the performance penalty of
> `VM.getNanoTimeAdjustment(offset)` which is less efficient.

*Answer:* `System.currentTimeMillis()` and `Clock.instant()` use the same time source.

Comment: Now I get the focus of the question and the reason of your comment...thanks for pointing me out this!

Comment: This makes it clear. One question tho - All these system clocks with nanosecond precision don't necessarily have nanosecond resolution, do they?

Comment: My Windows 10 seems to return time with precision of 100 nanoseconds in Java 9 or later, but the time only has a resolution of 1 millisecond. E.g. it returns `09:59:26.318623500`, but the next different time value after multiple calls to `LocalTime.now()` is `09:59:26.319619800`, i.e. 996300 nanoseconds (or ~1 ms) later.